# how to make bar total in chartjs same like user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I want to make the total bars 12 when i input 12. how to make the length of variable labels same like my input???

this is my code:

```
function updateChart() {
  let val = $("#num-input").val()
  let valNum = parseInt(val)
  console.log(valNum)
  
  let labels = []; // this length = bar total
  labels = $("#num-input").val()
  console.log(labels)

  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [10, 20, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45], // = value for each bar
    }]
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {}
  };

  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
}
```

this is my result

[image: result]

Comment: Are you trying to control how many bars you see on the chart?

Comment: yes, i have to turn the input (number) into length (into length of array NOT into array) of labels array but still clueless @nick

Comment: This question may give you a starting point - https://stackoverflow.com/q/69933941/2570277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because chart.js expects an array so you will need to make an array containing 12 labels first instead of passing the number 12 to the labels array:

```js
function updateChart() {
  let val = $("#num-input").val()
  let valNum = parseInt(val)
  console.log(valNum)
  
  let labels = []; // this length = bar total

  for (let i = 0; i < $("#num-input").val(); i++) {
    labels.push(i) // or any other value you want your label to have
  }

  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [10, 20, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45], // = value for each bar
    }]
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {}
  };

  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
}
```